# how to show user input in the body when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display a user input on a separate div, but only have it appear when a button is clicked. I think i have it set up but I'm just not sure how to display the input. can someone help me with how it can be done?

```js
<script>
    var callButt = document.getElementById("callButt");
    var userinput = document.getElementById("userinput");

    callButt.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("Call has been set");

    userinput.style.display = "block";

</script>
```

```html
<input id="callerIDInput" type="text" value="" >
<div id="userinput"> </div>

<button id='callButt'>CALL</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the [input value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) to the [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) of the div

```js
var callButt = document.getElementById("callButt");
var userinput = document.getElementById("userinput");
callButt.addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log("Call has been set");
      userinput.innerHTML = document.getElementById('callerIDInput').value
      })
```

```html
<input id="callerIDInput" type="text" value="">
<div id="userinput"> </div>

<button id='callButt'>CALL</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerHTML` of the DIV to set the value.

**HTML**

```
<input id="callerIDInput" type="text" value="">
<div id="userinput"> </div>

<button id='callButt' onclick="Display()">CALL</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function Display()
{
    var callButt = document.getElementById("callButt");
    var userinput = document.getElementById("userinput");
    var callerIDInput = document.getElementById("callerIDInput");
    console.log("Call has been set");
    userinput.style.display = "block";
    userinput.innerHTML = callerIDInput.value;
}
```